# What are all the types of Instance states with there respective State transition reason in AWS EC2 instance response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Example: 
Instance state: stopped
State transition reason message
Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [StateReason - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_StateReason.html):

- `Server.InsufficientInstanceCapacity`: There was insufficient capacity available to satisfy the launch request.
- `Server.InternalError`: An internal error caused the instance to terminate during launch.
- `Server.ScheduledStop`: The instance was stopped due to a scheduled retirement.
- `Server.SpotInstanceShutdown`: The instance was stopped because the number of Spot requests with a maximum price equal to or higher than the Spot price exceeded available capacity or because of an increase in the Spot price.
- `Server.SpotInstanceTermination`: The instance was terminated because the number of Spot requests with a maximum price equal to or higher than the Spot price exceeded available capacity or because of an increase in the Spot price.
- `Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown`: The instance was shut down using the shutdown -h command from the instance.
- `Client.InstanceTerminated`: The instance was terminated or rebooted during AMI creation.
- `Client.InternalError`: A client error caused the instance to terminate during launch.
- `Client.InvalidSnapshot.NotFound`: The specified snapshot was not found.
- `Client.UserInitiatedShutdown`: The instance was shut down using the Amazon EC2 API.
- `Client.VolumeLimitExceeded`: The limit on the number of EBS volumes or total storage was exceeded. Decrease usage or request an increase in your account limits.